# Database suggestion for chat app Java

Tags: java, database

I am building p2p Chat in Java and I need a DB for accounts, friendlists and whoIsOnline. My idea is to create a server, which is receiving periodicly KeepAlive messages and updates whoIsOnline list, then sends back to clients this list only for their friendlists. Any suggestion what DB should I use?

Comment: Use the one you're most familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is quite easy to learn. You find much tutorials for begginers in MySQL.
Here is a small example of creating the database and using the databse in java.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

I never had any problem with it and have done a lot with it.

Setting up a MySQL Server on your Server is also very well documented. Just search for it and you will find what fits you